# Run Spark-shell with error :SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I install spark on three nodes successfully. I can visit spark web UI and find every worker node and master node is active.

I can run the SparkPi example successfully.

My cluster info:
10.45.10.33(master&worker,hadoop-master,hadoop-slave)
10.45.10.34(worker,hadoop-slave)
10.45.10.35(worker,hadoop-slave)

But when I try to run "spark-shell --master yarn",it gave out the exception:

```
16/09/12 19:50:29 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:101)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:94)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/09/12 19:50:29 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
16/09/12 19:50:29 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2256)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:101)
  ... 47 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Here is my configuration:

1.spark-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/root/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_77
export SPARK_HOME=/root/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop classpath)
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_LIBARY_PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.45.10.33
SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=28686
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/root/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop/sparkdata/local
SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/root/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop/sparkdata/work
SPARK_LOG_DIR=/root/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop/logs
```

2. spark-defaults.conf

   spark.eventLog.enabled  true
   spark.eventLog.dir      hdfs://10.45.10.33/spark-event-log

3.slaves

```
10.45.10.33
10.45.10.34
10.45.10.35
```

Here is some log info:
yarn job logs:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/alluxio-core-client-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/Downloads/alluxio-master/core/client/target/alluxio-core-client-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/09/14 11:21:08 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/09/14 11:21:08 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/09/14 11:21:08 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/09/14 11:21:14 INFO ApplicationMaster: Preparing Local resources
16/09/14 11:21:15 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
```

yarn logs on runnong node:

```
2016-09-14 01:26:41,321 WARN alluxio.logger.type: Worker Client last execution took 2271 ms. Longer than the interval 1000
2016-09-14 06:13:10,905 WARN alluxio.logger.type: Worker Client last execution took 1891 ms. Longer than the interval 1000
2016-09-14 08:41:36,122 WARN alluxio.logger.type: Worker Client last execution took 1625 ms. Longer than the interval 1000
2016-09-14 10:41:49,426 WARN alluxio.logger.type: Worker Client last execution took 2441 ms. Longer than the interval 1000
2016-09-14 11:18:44,355 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1473752235721_0009_000002 (auth:SIMPLE)
2016-09-14 11:18:45,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 by user root
2016-09-14 11:18:45,447 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Creating a new application reference for app application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:18:45,601 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root IP=10.45.10.33  OPERATION=Start Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1473752235721_0009    CONTAINERID=container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:18:45,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1473752235721_0009 transitioned from NEW to INITING
2016-09-14 11:18:45,815 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Adding container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 to application application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:18:45,865 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1473752235721_0009 transitioned from INITING to RUNNING
2016-09-14 11:18:46,060 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2016-09-14 11:18:46,060 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:18:46,211 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.45.10.33:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1473752235721_0009/__spark_libs__8339309767420855025.zip transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2016-09-14 11:18:46,211 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.45.10.33:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1473752235721_0009/__spark_conf__.zip transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2016-09-14 11:18:46,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Created localizer for container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:18:47,083 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Writing credentials to the nmPrivate file /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001.tokens. Credentials list: 
2016-09-14 11:18:47,658 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Initializing user root
2016-09-14 11:18:47,761 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Copying from /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001.tokens to /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001.tokens
2016-09-14 11:18:47,765 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Localizer CWD set to /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009 = file:/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:20:54,352 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.45.10.33:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1473752235721_0009/__spark_libs__8339309767420855025.zip(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/filecache/10/__spark_libs__8339309767420855025.zip) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2016-09-14 11:20:55,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.45.10.33:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1473752235721_0009/__spark_conf__.zip(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/filecache/11/__spark_conf__.zip) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2016-09-14 11:20:55,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2016-09-14 11:20:57,298 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
2016-09-14 11:20:57,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
2016-09-14 11:20:58,338 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:21:07,134 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 26593 for container-id container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001: 50.3 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.2 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2016-09-14 11:21:15,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 26593 for container-id container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001: 90.9 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2016-09-14 11:21:15,224 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Process tree for container: container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 has processes older than 1 iteration running over the configured limit. Limit=2254857728, current usage = 2424918016
2016-09-14 11:21:15,412 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Container [pid=26593,containerID=container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 90.9 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 26593 26591 26593 26593 (bash) 1 0 115838976 119 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/userlogs/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher --arg '10.45.10.33:54976' --properties-file /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1> /root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/userlogs/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/stdout 2> /root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/userlogs/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/stderr 
    |- 26597 26593 26593 26593 (java) 811 62 2309079040 23149 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/root/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/userlogs/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher --arg 10.45.10.33:54976 --properties-file /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 

2016-09-14 11:21:15,451 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Removed ProcessTree with root 26593
2016-09-14 11:21:15,469 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to KILLING
2016-09-14 11:21:15,471 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:21:15,891 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 is : 143
2016-09-14 11:21:19,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2016-09-14 11:21:19,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009/container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:21:19,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Container Finished - KilleTARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1473752235721_0009    CONTAINERID=container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:21:19,813 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2016-09-14 11:21:19,813 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001 from application application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:21:19,813 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:21:21,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001
2016-09-14 11:21:21,531 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1473752235721_0009_02_000001]
2016-09-14 11:21:21,536 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1473752235721_0009 transitioned from RUNNING to APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP
2016-09-14 11:21:21,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_STOP for appId application_1473752235721_0009
2016-09-14 11:21:21,585 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1473752235721_0009 transitioned from APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP to FINISHED
2016-09-14 11:21:21,589 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.loghandler.NonAggregatingLogHandler: Scheduling Log Deletion for application: application_1473752235721_0009, with delay of 10800 seconds
2016-09-14 11:21:21,592 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1473752235721_0009
```

How do I solve this problem? Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: Have you tried to launch it with additional argument like `--deploy-mode client` ?

Comment: Execute jps and check if HDFS and YARN are working. Please check also YARN logs

Comment: You do not need Spark Master and Workers when running on YARN. Please check if the ResourceManager and NodeManagers are running fine. Try opening the YARN UI on port 8088 and check for nodes available.

Comment: MASTER=yarn-cluster spark-shell

Comment: @Zyoma I tried to run in client deploy mode and it gave out the same error.

Comment: @T.Gawęda I use jps to check and find that HDFS and YARN is working.The info in YARN logs on master and slave indicates only that the YARN job failed.

Comment: @RakeshRakshit ResourceManager and NodeManagers are running fine and I can see these nods on YARN UI on port 8088

Comment: @ZahiroMor Would you mind saying it more concrete?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I have checked the log about the spark job and find the only is "ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM". I name my directory as "spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop" because I downloaded the "pre-build with user-provided hadoop" package.

Comment: Can you post the entire logs somewhere as I think that the ERROR message: "ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM" is due to memory/vcores constraints in YARN that did not let Spark to run.

Comment: I have added the entire yarn logs to my question. Thanks for your help I find the log says "container ...is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 90.9 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container. But I am confused why container use virtual memory rather than physical memory? I still have enough physical memory actually.

Answer (score 2):

I was receiveing this ERROR : 'Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!'

and landed on this page without answer.. If anyone has the same error, for me the solution was to open Spark ports.

On version Spark 3.1.2, running in Ubuntu 20.04 you have to specify some things in the cluster, so the ports don´t be assigned randomly:

in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.driver.bindAddress                10.0.0.1
spark.driver.host                       10.0.0.1
spark.shuffle.service.port              7337
spark.ui.port                           4040
spark.blockManager.port                 31111
spark.driver.blockManager.port          32222
spark.driver.port                       33333
```

in spark-env.sh:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=10.0.0.1
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
```

and in workers you put the adresses ot the datanodes.